# $.extend changes value for both parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 2 objects

```
var var1 = {a: 1, b: 2};
var var2 = {b: 3, c:5};
```

Now, I want var 3 with value like this - `var3 = {a:1, b:3, c:5}`

I want to achieve that without changing the values of var1 and var2 using `jquery extend()` method.

How can I achieve that?

After I run following command

```
var var3 = $.extend(var1, var2)
```

Now, the result is this

```
var1 = {a: 1, b: 3, c: 5} // var1 is getting changed and i dont want this
var2 = {b: 3, c:5};
var3 = {a: 1, b: 3, c: 5}
```

var1 is now equal to var3 where as I do not want to change the value of var1 or var2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var var3 = $.extend({}, var1, var2);
```

The first object provided will be mutated, so just run extend on three objects, with the first being empty.

Answer (score 1):

That's how `$.extend()` works: it always modifies the first object in the argument list. If you don't want that, then:

```
var var3 = $.extend({}, var1, var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var var3 = $.extend(var3,var1,var2);
```

[jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)